# Keeps terminating while using screen with running run.sh file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

I'm a newbie on using screen. I'm trying to run my `run.sh` file from a docker container with screen command.

However, it keeps automatically terminating when I typed the below command.

```
screen -S rand1 ./run.sh
```

So I found some solutions from the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428713/create-a-screen-session-with-a-bash-script-using-contab/428719) but didn't work for me.

Can anybody help me out here?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an infinite loop at the end of `./run.sh` could help.

Comment: @uprego Thanks for commenting! :) You mean from this command-line? `screen -S rand1 ./run.sh`

Comment: Yes. If you wanted to go that way, you might want to make that "infinite loop at end" depend on some argument if you need the previous behavior to stay default.

Comment: @uprego Starting an interactive shell would be more useful than uselessly spinning in a loop.

Comment: Do you mean `screen -Si rand1 ./run.sh`?

Comment: Do you mean `screen -S rand1 'sh -i ./run.sh'`? If that works, couldn't agree more with you.

Comment: Post the whole docker boot command, the interactive flag might help passed to `docker` itself. Maybe related: https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/11266726.